# Hot reloading with create-react-native app on vagrant

Tags: react-native, vagrant, create-react-native-app

I have used **`create-react-native-app`** and expo to build an application on a **`vagrant ubuntu`** and run it using yarn start.

> When i make changes to my file on my host machine, the changes are not
>   reflected.
>
> With create-react-app, CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true worked and all my
>   changes were reflected instantly but this is not the case for native.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

Comment: What version of npm are you using? create-react-native-app has bugs with npm 5.

Comment: i am using npm 5.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `yarn start` instead of `npm start` since your current of npm (5) has issues with create-react-native-app as of today.

Comment: Hi Arielle, i have actually been using yarn and i get the same problem

Comment: Interesting, do you mind sharing your repo on github so we can take a deeper look? Do you not see any errors in your terminal?